# Validating a string parameter using the Validating string plugin in declarative pipeline

Tags: validation, jenkins, parameters, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to validate a string parameter to a specific regex.

Is there a possibility to have a Valid or Not Valid result in a reactive mode or through a button in the Build with Parameters screen without starting the pipeline?

```
>     string(name: 'Add', defaultValue: 'none', description: 'Add a new label using the label key-name=value'),
>     validatingString(name: "test", value:"${params.Add}", defaultValue: "", regex: /^abc-[0-9]+$/, failedValidationMessage:
> "Validation failed!", description: "ABC")
```

The above does not work and I have a stuck Validation failed message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `string` parameter and a `validatingString` parameter, instead use only a `validatingString` to hold your string value and add the required validation to that string.
Try the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        validatingString(name: "Add", defaultValue: 'none', description: "Add a new label using the label key-name=value", regex: /^abc-[0-9]+$/, failedValidationMessage: "Validation failed!")
    }
    stages {
       ...
   }
}
```